# curl response is "internal server error", how to resolve

Tags: php, curl

Hi I have written a scraper to get data from a API , its working fine in localhost but when i testing it in my shared host im getting this :

```
[200] => 20211019@31270.00@30320.00@31770.00@30700.00@30340.00@31910.00 ... (Long Text)
[201] => The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred (this will shown as a result after that)
[202] => ... same
```

my shared host ini settings :

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 35000
max_input_time = 18000
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 280M
post_max_size = 100M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"
upload_max_filesize = 100M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

my code source (it's getting 600 stock company prices):
sample : http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=44818950263583523&Top=999999&A=1

```
foreach ($namads as $namex => $n) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/InstTradeHistory.aspx?i=' . $n . '&Top=400&A=1' );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    print_r($data);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

how can i found what caused the problem it doesn't show me what the problem is exactly , i dont think its a problem from api server because its working fine in localhost.

you can see the results in https://ravandro.com/historical.php

Comment: It would appear the internal server error is coming from `members.tsetmc.com` and not you. Maybe they have a rate limit.

Comment: @cherrydt maybe but it's working fine in my localhost , i have added a link for my script please check it out , thanks for your comment

Comment: Maybe your own IP address is handled differently than your server's, from their perspective... You could try using different proxies.

Comment: I have used print_r for minimal output , result is the same @user3783243

Comment: If a remote site, not under your control, is behaving unpredictably, the answer is always to contact that site’s host. It doesn’t matter if this is a client-facing browser, a backend API call, or a screen scraper.